# Sell on Google Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

I developed several apps for Chrome web browser and plan to sell it on Chrome Web Store.
Is this place suitable to do that?

Let me explain why I doubt.

- Firstly, I can't find any paid app on Chrome Web Store. But I found information, FAQs and guidelines etc. about app selling in the official documentation of the webstore!
- I also can't find news, overviews or any articles about Chrome Web Store after December 2011. It seems, there are no fresh news.

So, what is going on with Chrome Web Store?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FAQ's](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-gen-11) you can in fact have apps that require payment first to download/use much like the Apple app store. I would suspect that you never see paid ones, simply because if there is something close to it already free then of course not many people would go for the paid one therefore it's probably not popular.

I would assume since their official FAQ's state that they have paid apps that they are telling the truth. I hope this answers your question!